# ASP.NET Core 2 - ReSharper "Create Razor View" adds new view to Pages folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, resharper, asp.net-core-2.0

I've started trying out new ASP.NET Core 2 for building an MVC Web App, and it looks good so far...

Except that when I create Views from my controller actions, ReSharper creates them in a *Pages* folder, rather than the *Views* folder (where I generally like to keep my *Views* ;-) )

[image: resharper create razor view]
[image: view in pages folder]

ReSharper doesn't behave this way for regular ASP.NET Web Apps (not core), it puts the views in the correct view folder, so this looks to be to do with Core / Core 2.

**What is resharper using to decide where to create the view?**

**How can I change this behavior** so that it creates the views in the traditional location?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Resharper and I'm suspecting it might be related to the new [Razor Pages Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio) .net core 2 team just released.

So, perhaps it would be better for you to fill an issue on Reshaper's Bug Tracking System.

However, I've managed to setup a workaround. I'm sharing the steps here, just in case you need to fix this ASAP and when JetBrains fixes the issue - if it finally is an issue :) - you can remove this patch.

1. Install the nuget package for Jetbrains Annotations.

   ```
   Install-Package JetBrains.Annotations
   ```
2. Create a .cs file on the root of your asp.net core project - I've named it ResharperConfig.cs - with the following content:

   ```
   using JetBrains.Annotations;

   [assembly: AspMvcMasterLocationFormat("~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat("~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaMasterLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
   ```
3. Build your project and restart VS. (this was important for me).
4. When you reopen the solution, R# will recognize the locations for the views. Now you can go and create views from the actions the way you're used to.

[image: Resharper issue]

Hope this helps!

Comment: So... this is a pretty epic answer, and clearly well researched and probably works, and I'll mark it as accepted. However, I updated R# before seeing your answer, and it now works correctly! Thank you anyway - it's taught me about how to customize the R# behavior.

Comment: @Erresen thanks a lot for your kind words. Actually I'd like you to know that I tested using the latest version of R# I had available - 2017.2.1 and as I was able to reproduce the issue just like you described I thought it was a bug and started researching until I was able to "fix it", so this makes it even more annoying. Which version did you have and to which one did you update?

Comment: That's very strange then! I'm using VS2017 Community and for R# was on either 2016.2 or 2016.3.2 (sorry, I neglected to note the previous version down), and updated to 2017.2.1. It's very strange that the update fixed it for me, but not for you...

Comment: We could go crazy speculating here :) - maybe after the update R# overwrote the config values with the correct ones for instance - but I don't see much benefit in doing that. I'm glad it worked for you anyways.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. :)

Comment: See resharper issue [RSRP-465732](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465732), planned to fix in 2018.1

Comment: I'm using Rider right now, this problem still persist. Anybody knows how to fix it ? I  didn't find any solution to it.

Comment: Thank gawd been driving me mad for ages (years) this. I commented on that issue on RSRP in 22 Oct 2018 and it still isn;t fixed for old MVC asp.net projects! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This still applies to the `ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)` .NET 6 template installed with VS 2022. R# generates views in `\Pages` by default, which is the wrong location anyway.

With the ResharperConfig.cs (as described above) now R# creates the views in the right place, assuming the View's parent folder exists.

My entity centered Clean Architecture configuration:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;

[assembly: AspMvcMasterLocationFormat("~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat("~/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcAreaMasterLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcAreaViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcAreaPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
```

This `[assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat("~/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml")]` makes sure R# generates views in this location:
`\<Controller>\Views\<Action>.cshtml`

You should combine that with a `IViewLocationExpander` to instruct .NET to also look in the same location to find the views while rendering them:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

public class CleanArchViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return viewLocations.Select(l => l.Replace("/Views/{1}/", "/{1}/Views/"));
    }
}
```

Which you then register in `Program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(
    options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CleanArchViewLocationExpander());
    });
```

Happy coding!